# How to add data labels for a treemap in highcharter in r?

Tags: r, highcharts, data-visualization, treemap, r-highcharter

I want to add data labels for a treemap I have created. I am using this treemap for an image so having the `pts` and `fgpct` for each box would be helpful. I want what's listed in the tooltip and the legend to appear in each box.

**My code:**

```
library(highcharter)

gamelogs %>%
  filter(slugTeam == "MEM") %>%
  group_by(namePlayer) %>%
  summarise(pts = sum(pts), fgpct = sum(fgm) / sum(fga)) %>%
  hchart("treemap", hcaes(name = namePlayer, value = pts, color = fgpct)) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Grizzlies Scoring") %>%
  hc_subtitle(text = "Shaded by Field Goal %") %>%
  hc_chart(
    backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF' # Chart Background Color
  ) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE,
               filename = "Grizzlies Scoring")
```

**My Output:**
[image: Grizzlies Team Points Breakdown]

**The output I would like:**
[image]

This  output would have the points 1,041 in the box and also the fgpct of 49% that is shown in the legend. Anyway to add the data labels using highcharter treemap?

Comment: Basically, you'd like to display this additional information above each dataLabel? I wonder if you need to edit a tooltip for this (it reacts dynamically to the user's interaction). Instead, wouldn't it be better to just adapt the appropriate format for dataLabelka to contain this information?

Comment: Hey, I think I might not have explained it right. I want what is listed in the tooltip and the legend to be in every box. So if I took a screenshot of the treemap, all of the information will be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
gamelogs %>%
  filter(slugTeam == "MEM") %>%
  group_by(namePlayer) %>%
  summarise(pts = sum(pts), fgpct = round(sum(fgm) / sum(fga),digits=2)) %>% 
  hchart("treemap", hcaes(name = namePlayer, value = pts, color = fgpct),
         dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.namePlayer}<br/>{point.pts} pts<br/>{point.fgpct} fgpct'),
         tooltip = list(pointFormat = "{point.namePlayer}: {point.pts}, {point.fgpct}%")) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Grizzlies Scoring") %>%
  hc_subtitle(text = "Shaded by Field Goal %") %>%
  hc_chart(
    backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF' # Chart Background Color
  ) %>%
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE,
               filename = "Grizzlies Scoring") %>% 
  hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE)
```

you will get this output

[image: output]

Comment: This code doesn't change anything. I want what's listed in the tooltip and the legend to appear in each box.

Comment: Hey, I think I might not have explained it right. I want what is listed in the tooltip and the legend to be in every box. So if I took a screenshot of the treemap, all of the information will be there. For example, the 3 boxes you have shown do not show the information for points and field goal percentage in every box.

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to change the fgpct to an actual %? For example, Marc Gasol would have a 42% field goal percentage instead of .42 (which is the same thing). Also making the size of the pts and fgpct smaller would be helpful too.

Comment: Two changes should do it: one: `fgpct = 100*round(sum(fgm) / sum(fga),digits=2)`, and two: `dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,...<br/>{point.fgpct}%')`

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I am trying to use `dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, fontSize = '8pt'` to make the pts and fgpct smaller in each box.